# Implement a mark on the photo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash

On the site we need to implement a mark on the photograph. By type as in facebook. It is desirable but not necessary that the selection of the object was not the rectangle, and polygon. There is a ready-realization? It does not matter what technology to use php, flash, and other, exotic but not necessary:)

Answer (score 1):

Use this php [Image Masking Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1464-PHP-Apply-masks-to-an-image-and-output-the-cut-image.html).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to burn the logo into the image, thus, server-technology is required (not flash).

There may be some ready libraries that does it, I made a HQ solution with PHP-GD a couple of years ago and a few hints:

- Image will loose quality since you'll resave (assuming jpeg images). Therefore, original image, before burning, should be twize the size of final output. (Adding jpeg-quality doesn't help much)
- Add transparent text or image, and shade it so it works on both light and dark photos.

regards,

//t

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [PHPthumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) library for many projects, including watermarking, it doesn't really matter if you are showing proper thumbs or larger images. It needs the GD library or ImageMagick though.

Also, there are a few similar answers here in SO that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=watermarking+php